# Un-remember Remote debugger credentials

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-authentication, remote-debugging

Now I've been doing some remote debugging on my surface using the Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor.

I've been using windows Authentication to connect to the remote debugging monitor, and it's been working successfully.

Today, started up the remote debugging monitor, but I clicked the 'Remember Credentials' check-box, and now I'm getting the window:

```
A remote operation is taking longer than expected
```

window, followed by a window saying:

```
There were deployment errors.  Continue?
```

- is there a way to un-remember my credentials?
- is there maybe another issue that I'm not accounting for?

In the meantime, I'm able to run the remote debugger if I opt not to use any authentication, But It would be best if I could go back to using Windows Authentication.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe that is stored in and can be managed from Control Panel\User Accounts\Credential Manager.