# How to change saved user on remote debug Visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am using "remote debug" to debug on another PC. On the first run I checked a checkbox "save user" and now I cannot change a user to login with another user. Can some one help to solve this problem?

Comment: Could clearing cache help?

Comment: Unfortunately cache clear didn't help.
What i already did:
Cleared everything from ...AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_07205207\ComponentModelCache
And from AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation
and from AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio
and \AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSCommon
and then run command devenv /resetuserdata

Comment: Dont know if this could be of help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14485967/un-remember-remote-debugger-credentials

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. This was the answer what i was looking for. Now everything works!